# Usually Geiger tubes have a recommended 1 to 5 megaohm anode load. What determines that value and what is the effect of increasing the value?

Tags: resistance, load

I think title is sufficient.   Changes?   Dead time, signal out amplitude, plateau character, etc.

Comment: https://www.cpp.edu/~pbsiegel/phy432/labman/geiger.pdf

Answer (score 0):

> Usually Geiger tubes have a recommended 1 to 5 megaohm anode load. What determines that value and what is the effect of increasing the value?

From this [https://mini.physics.sunysb.edu/~mdawber/phy252:geigerdecay](https://mini.physics.sunysb.edu/%7Emdawber/phy252:geigerdecay)

The characteristic "Voltage versus Current" or **"Current versus Voltage"** must be known.
Here an example where "current" is the number of pair e-/ion collected with some "particle" ... (just remember what is 1 A, One amp is defined as 6.28* 10^18 electrons per second.).

Changing the resistance (as in case color "ocre") ...
NB : current is logarithmic, so "load line" are not "straight line" !, only one "end" are ok),
... changes also the "load line", so one can see that we change the "region" of working of the "Geiger tube"

For reference, here is how looks "load line" in vertical "log" axis.(parameter R = 1Meg -> 5 Meg, step 1 Meg).

[image]

[image]